# Animation: Android AnimationDrawable not working in some devices

Tags: android, android-animation

Hey I am using an XML animation list to run a simple drawable animation. It's working fine in lower end device like Samsung Galaxy y(ldpi), and micromax canvas 2(dual core, hdpi). But it's lagging heavily in Micromax canvas a120(quad core, xhdpi). It's showing the first and last frame only. Here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<animation-list android:id="@+id/selected8" android:oneshot="true"    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/smile" android:duration="20" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/smile1" android:duration="20" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/smile2" android:duration="20" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/smile3" android:duration="20" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/smile4" android:duration="20" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/smile5" android:duration="20" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/smile6" android:duration="20" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/smile7" android:duration="20" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/smile8" android:duration="20" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/smile9" android:duration="20" />

</animation-list>
```

This is the java code:

```
  imgView1.setBackgroundResource(imageResource);
  frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) imgView1.getBackground();
  imgView1.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
     imgView1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

     frameAnimation.start();

        }
   });
```

How can I make the animation uniform for all devices? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: My guess is that it is playing as it should and that the lower end devices are lagging. 20 milliseconds is really fast.